# Vim: Good AutoCompletion Plugin for Python and PHP

Tags: php, python, vim, autocomplete, ctags

I use Vim with ctags for development. I found ctags to be very useful in going to definitions, but I don't know a good plugin to make use of ctags for clever auto completion. It seems that the default Vim auto completion is not good. When I write set omnifunc? in Vim, I get this:

```
omnifunction=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

I do know about OmniComplete for C++, but I don't know any good plugin for Python and PHP. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python, you can use the .vimrc file specified here:

[Ultimate Vim Python setup.](https://dev.launchpad.net/UltimateVimPythonSetup)

I think you will like it :)

Happy vimming and Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you very much, I liked it. But I spent sometime trying to tune it and get the other plugins to work. Do you have similar good plugins for PHP? Also, JavaScript?

Comment: Humm... so sorry, but I usually don't code on PHP or JS, so I don't have Vim properly tuned for that languages :( Good luck with your search!

Answer (score 2):

You can use following:

For Python: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30

For PHP: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571

Comment: This is not what I asked for really, but they are useful anyway.